# What is the difference between Cloud Computing and Grid Computing?

Tags: cloud, terminology, grid-computing

What are the significant differences between **Cloud Computing** and **Grid Computing** ? What are the precise definations and target application domains for both ? I'm looking for conceptual insights along with technicalities.

Like **Windows Azure** is a Cloud OS, do we have anytihng such for Grid Computing ?

In past I did work on distributed and parallel computing and I used the librariries like PVM and MPI for processing distribution. Out of curiosity I wanted to know If Grid Computing is **distributed computing** extended over internet ?

Comment: Is Windows Azure a cloud OS? It is a PAAS. I do not think it has the whole OS capability.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Grid computing is where more than one computer coordinates to solve a problem together. Often used for problems involving a lot of number crunching, which can be easily parallelisable.

Cloud computing is where an application doesn't access resources it requires directly, rather it accesses them through something like a *service*. So instead of talking to a specific hard drive for storage, and a specific CPU for computation, etc. it talks to some service that provides these resources. The service then maps any requests for resources to its physical resources, in order to provide for the application. Usually the service has access to a large amount of physical resources, and can dynamically allocate them as they are needed.

In this way, if an application requires only a small amount of some resource, say computation, then the service only allocates a small amount, say on a single physical CPU (that may be shared with some other application using the service). If the application requires a large amount of some resource, then the service allocates that large amount, say a *grid* of CPUs. The application is *relatively* oblivious to this, and all the complex handling and coordination is performed by the service, not the application. In this way the application can *scale* well.

For example a web site written "on the cloud" may share a server with many other web sites while it has a low amount of traffic, but may be moved to its own dedicated server, or grid of servers, if it ever has massive amounts of traffic. This is all handled by the cloud service, so the application shouldn't have to be modified drastically to cope.

A *cloud* would usually use a grid. A grid is not necessarily a cloud or part of a cloud.

Wikipedia articles: [Grid computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grid_computing), [Cloud computing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloud_computing).

Comment: +1 for sentence "A cloud would usually use a grid. A grid is not necessarily a cloud or part of a cloud."

Comment: Website example explains cleared the concept

Answer (score 9):

This is the perfect answer for [difference between Cloud Computing and Grid Computing ?](http://www.ibeehosting.com/blog/what-is-the-difference-between-cloud-computing-and-grid-computing.html)
Check this:

Answer (score 3):

You should really read Wikipedia for in-depth understanding. 
In short, 
Cloud computing means you develop/run your software remotely on remote platform. This can be either using remote virtual infrastructure (amazon EC2), remote platform (google app engine), or remote application (force.com or gmail.com).

Grid computing means using many physical hardwares to do computations (in the broad sense) as if it was a single hardware. This means that you can run your application on several distinct machines at the same time.

not *very* accurate but enough to get you started.

Answer (score 3):

I would say that the basic difference is this:

**Grids** are used as computing/storage platform.

We start talking about **cloud** computing when it offers services. I would almost say that cloud computing is higher-level grid. Now I know these are not definitions, but maybe it will make it more clear.

As far as application domains go, grids require users (developers mostly) to actually create services from low-level functions that grid offers. Cloud will offer complete blocks of functionality that you can use in your application.

Example (you want to create physical simulation of ball dropping from certain height):
**Grid**: Study how to compute physics on a computer, create appropriate code, optimize it for certain hardware, think about paralellization, set inputs send application to grid and wait for answer

**Cloud**: Set diameter of a ball, material from pre-set types, height from which the ball is dropping, etc and ask for results

I would say that if you created OS for grid, you would actually create cloud OS.

Comment: Is this an analogy or an example?  It might be an accurate analogy, but not very useful.  As an example, I think it is incorrect and misleading.

Answer (score 3):

A **Grid** is a hardware and software infrastructure that clusters and integrates high-end computers, networks, databases, and scientific instruments from multiple sources to form a virtual supercomputer on which users can work collaboratively within virtual organisations

Grid is Mostly free used by academic research etc.

**Clouds** are a large pool of easily usable and accessible
virtualized resources (such as hardware, development
platforms and/or services). These resources can be
dynamically reconfigured to adjust to a variable load
(scale), allowing also for an optimum resource utilization.
This pool of resources is typically exploited by a pay peruse
model in which guarantees are offered by the
Infrastructure Provider by customized service level
agreements.

Cloud is not free. It is a service, provided by different service providers and they charge according to your work done.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of good answers to this question already but another way to take a look at it is the cloud (ala Amazon's AWS) is good for interactive use cases and the grid (ala High Performance Computing) is good for batch use cases.

Cloud is interactive in that you can get resources on demand via self service.  The code you run on VMs in the cloud, such as the Apache web server, can server clients interactively.

Grid is batch in that you submit jobs to a job queue after obtaining the credentials from some HPC authority to do so.  The code you run on the grid waits in that queue until there are sufficient resources to execute it.

There are good use cases for both styles of computing.

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Computing is For Service Oriented  where as Grid Computing is for Application Oriented. Grid computing is used to build Virtual supercomputer using a middler ware to achieve a common task that can be shared among several resources. most probably this task will be kind of computing or data storage.

Cloud computing is providing services over the internet through several servers uses Virtualization.In cloud computing either you can provide service in three types Iaas , Paas, Saas . 
This will give you solution when you don't have any resources for a short time Business service over the Internet.

Answer (score -1):

Cloud Computing is a large group of interconnected computers.The data are hidden form the user.
Grid computing is more than one computers interconnected to resolve the problem.grid computing is worked in cloud computing.